# error cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get some errors in my code below could any one help?

> error cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'   The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.File.Exists(string)' has some invalid arguments

```
string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=x; Password=x;");
cn.Open();

OdbcCommand sc = new OdbcCommand(string.Format("SELECT picturepath FROM Pictures WHERE UserID ='{0}'", theUserId), cn);
OdbcDataReader reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
if (System.IO.File.Exists(reader[0]))
{  // error cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'
   // The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.File.Exists(string)' has some invalid arguments
    System.IO.File.Delete(reader[0]);
}  // error cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'
   // The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.File.Delete(string)' has some invalid arguments
}
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Careful... you've got a SQL injection vulnerability here.

Comment: yup I know :) thanks tho

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace `reader[0]` with either:

```
reader.GetString(0)
```

or

```
Convert.ToString(reader[0])
```

(since `reader[0]` is for arbitrary data, so typed as `object` - but that method expects a `string`)

Answer (score 1):

The quick solution is this:

```
// note addition of "as string"
if (System.IO.File.Exists(reader[0] as string))
```

However you should be sure that the element at that position really is a string.

Comment: Actually, I'd use `(string)reader[0]` if going this route; the exception message will be clearer if we get it wrong - cast vs null-arg)

Comment: See that too often. `as` should almost always be followed by a `null` check, never used directly.

Answer (score 0):

If reader[0] is indeed a string object, reader[0].ToString() will return the string value.

While debugging, you can check what type reader[0] by calling the get type method in the immediate window.

e.g. reader[0].GetType()

Answer (score 0):

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select fact_code,fact_cost,fact_date from factor where fact_date between '" + int.Parse(comboBox2.SelectedItem )+ "/" + int.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedItem) + "/" + int.Parse(comboBox3.SelectedItem) + "'and '" + int.Parse(comboBox5.SelectedItem) + "/" + int.Parse(comboBox4.SelectedItem) + "/" + int.Parse(comboBox6.SelectedItem) + "'", con);
                DataSet dt = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.Tables[0];
```